# can you use "over" to mean "relative to"?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> They prefer this method because of the cost reduction **over** traditional techniques.

Can "over" be used in this case instead of "relative to"? I feel like the sentence can be easily understood, but I'm not able to find any definitions of "over" to support its use here.

Comment: prefer one thing over another is a perfectly standard usage.

Comment: If they'd preferred to *avoid* this method because of the cost **increase** over [cheaper alternatives], I'd have no problem. But because of the semantic clash between "reduction" and "over", I personally would never use them together like this. It's stylistically clumsy, imho.

Comment: For a "quick & dirty" fix, just relocate the troublesome element (and change the preposition, for the icing on the cake): *They prefer this method **to** traditional techniques because of the cost reduction*.

Comment: The formula is *They prefer X over Y because of Z.*  The way you have written the sentence, *They prefer X because of Z over Y,* is difficult to understand.  I had to read it twice to extract the meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, "over" is commonly used to indicate relative preference.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over):

> **over**
> *preposition*
> **2 b** —used as a function word to indicate superiority, advantage, or preference

Answer (score 2):

Given sentence: They prefer this method because of the cost reduction over traditional techniques.

To use *over* as a comparison, you can do this:

They prefer **this method over traditional techniques** because of cost reduction.

For over to be used that way it needs to come right after the word or phrase to which it refers.

Answer (score 1):

I think "over" in this context means ["more than"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/over#:%7E:text=A2-,more%20than,-%3A). For the sake of clarity, I would rephrase it like this: "They prefer this method to traditional techniques because the cost of this method is cheaper"